# No matches found for Find: Elements matching predicate '"" IN identifiers' from input

Tags: swift, unit-testing, uitest, xctestcase

Im getting this error on the Unit Test:

```
No matches found for Find: Elements matching predicate '"addressSearchBar" IN identifiers' from input {(
    SearchField, 0x60000038a420, traits: 146029151232, label: 'Search on Google Maps', placeholderValue: 'Search on Google Maps'
)}
```

This the unit Test:

```
func testTypeSearch() {
    app.searchFields["addressSearchBar"].typeText("Springfield")
}
```

Ive been looking at this post:
[Xcode UITest sometimes does not find property of XCUIElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075816/xcode-uitest-sometimes-does-not-find-property-of-xcuielement?rq=1)

And Ive set isAccessibilityElement

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    view.isAccessibilityElement = false
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}
```

and here:

```
searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.isAccessibilityElement = false
searchBar.accessibilityIdentifier = "addressSearchBar"
```

I've tried multiple solutions and I didn't manage to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

can try accessibility property set to true

The default value for this property is false unless the receiver is a standard UIKit control, in which case the value is true.

```
searchBar = UISearchBar()
searchBar.isAccessibilityElement = true
searchBar.accessibilityIdentifier = "addressSearchBar"
```